# How to change background image onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to implement `onClick` change background image :
There are multiple element with same name as class

```css
.click{
    background-image: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/phone-icon.png");
    }
```

```html
<a class='click' onclick="$(this).css('background-image','http://previews.123rf.com/images/runlenarun/runlenarun1411/runlenarun141100068/33499512-Single-flat-icon-with-long-shadow-for-web-applications-email-icons-design-Envelope-with-close-sign-V-Stock-Vector.jpg');"></a>
<a class='click' onclick="$(this).css('background-image','http://previews.123rf.com/images/runlenarun/runlenarun1411/runlenarun141100068/33499512-Single-flat-icon-with-long-shadow-for-web-applications-email-icons-design-Envelope-with-close-sign-V-Stock-Vector.jpg');"></a>
<a class='click' onclick="$(this).css('background-image','http://previews.123rf.com/images/runlenarun/runlenarun1411/runlenarun141100068/33499512-Single-flat-icon-with-long-shadow-for-web-applications-email-icons-design-Envelope-with-close-sign-V-Stock-Vector.jpg');"></a>
```

When I click on any of the `<a>` tag, the image changes to any other image onClick. Element `id` cant be used. Only class. Please help

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rcfbgnck/)

Comment: This snippet is wrong. It doesn't reproduce anything.ç

Comment: Your fiddle is wrong. Please update it.

Comment: Wondering to see 2 upvotes for unclear question.

Comment: Do you mean to change the background image when you click on any link?

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.click').click(function(){
    var img= $(this).data('img');
    $(this).css('background-image','url("'+img+'")');
  });
});
```

```css
.click{
    background-image: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/phone-icon.png");
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  display:inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='click' data-img="http://previews.123rf.com/images/runlenarun/runlenarun1411/runlenarun141100068/33499512-Single-flat-icon-with-long-shadow-for-web-applications-email-icons-design-Envelope-with-close-sign-V-Stock-Vector.jpg"></a>
<a class='click' data-img='http://previews.123rf.com/images/runlenarun/runlenarun1411/runlenarun141100068/33499512-Single-flat-icon-with-long-shadow-for-web-applications-email-icons-design-Envelope-with-close-sign-V-Stock-Vector.jpg'></a>
<a class='click' data-img='http://previews.123rf.com/images/runlenarun/runlenarun1411/runlenarun141100068/33499512-Single-flat-icon-with-long-shadow-for-web-applications-email-icons-design-Envelope-with-close-sign-V-Stock-Vector.jpg'></a>
```

Check this. I created a example for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with CSS alone by using the `:active` (or `:focus`) state to change the `background-image`. The trick is to set a `transition` on the `background` element, giving it a ridiculously high delay in the normal state and resetting it to `0s` when you change the image, like so:

```css
a{
  background-image:url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/phone-icon.png);
  background-size:contain;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100px;
  transition-delay:9999s;
  transition-property:background-image;
  width:100px;
}
a:active,a:focus{
  background-image:url(http://previews.123rf.com/images/runlenarun/runlenarun1411/runlenarun141100068/33499512-Single-flat-icon-with-long-shadow-for-web-applications-email-icons-design-Envelope-with-close-sign-V-Stock-Vector.jpg);
  transition-delay:0s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
```